# Setting Devise omniauth_path_prefix doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, omniauth

I'm working on a Rails-based API. I recently started attempting to version it. (I'm using the [Versionist](https://github.com/bploetz/versionist) gem, in case it matters) One version ('v2') uses Devise and Omniauth to authenticate users through Facebook/Twitter.

I want all the routes associated with this version to have the appropriate version prefix (so `users/:username/foo` becomes `v2/users/:username/foo`, etc.), but I've already found out that putting `devise_for` inside the `api_version` block prevents the Devise helpers (`current_user`, `user_signed_in?`, etc.) from working, so it continues to live outside the block:

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :user, :path => '', :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks'}, :skip => [:registrations, :confirmations, :sessions, :passwords]

api_version(:module => "V2", :path=>"v2") do

  resources :authentications, :only => [:update, :destroy]

  devise_scope :user do
    post 'login' => 'sessions#create', :as => 'user_session'
    get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
    post 'password' => 'devise/passwords#create'
    put 'password' => 'devise/passwords#update'
  end

end
```

Everything seemed great... except the Devise-generated omniauth routes:

rake routes output:

```
 user_omniauth_authorize      /auth/:provider(.:format)
 user_omniauth_callback       /auth/:action/callback(.:format)
```

Now, some google-fu revealed that there's a devise configuration setting for this, so I added the following to our devise initializer (`config/initializers/devise.rb`):

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.omniauth_path_prefix = 'v2/auth'
end
```

Now, rake routes produces paths that look sensible:

```
user_omniauth_authorize     /v2/auth/:provider(.:format)          v2/users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/(?!)/}
user_omniauth_callback      /v2/auth/:action/callback(.:format)          v2/users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:(?!))
```

However, when I attempt to access this route by calling `api.localhost/v2/auth/facebook`, I get a routing error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/v2/auth/facebook")
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the provider name in the routes so they don't match the `facebook` part in `/v2/auth/facebook`. The correct route destination should look something like `v2/users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook)`.

Have you specified the provider in the user model?

```
devise_for ..., :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
```

For the record, I'm using Rails 3.2 and Devise 3.0 and the altered route seems to work (I haven't gone further yet to see if something else will break).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the project has changed enough over the past ten months that I'm no longer able to determine if it works.